# Queueing average time with 3 servers

Tags: stochastic-processes, exponential-distribution, queueing-theory

Suppose the bank has three service lines. Customers arrive to the first, second, and third lines according to an exponential distribution with rates $\lambda = 3$, $\lambda = 4$, and $\lambda = 8$.

Furthermore, sometimes the service clerks must call the supervisor to approve a request. The probabilities of needing to call the supervisor at each desk are

$$p_1 = \frac{1}{4},\quad p_2 = \frac{1}{6},\quad p_3=\frac{1}{9}$$

respectively. What is the average time, in minutes, between customers being referred to the supervisor?

---

If I understand correctly, this is a M/G/$3$ system. Hence, the average time between referrals would be

$$
\mathbb{E}W_{\text{M}/\text{G}/3} = \left(\frac{K^2}{2} + \frac{1}{2}\right)\mathbb{E}W_{\text{M}/M/3},
$$

where $C \approx .4$, which is the standard deviation divided by the mean of $(p_1, p_2, p_3)$.

However, there is suppose to be a relatively straight forward solution, and the above doesn't seem to get me that. Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be solved using two somewhat well known results:

1. We note that when looking only at a single service line $i$ ($i \in \{1,2,3\}$) we can use the result that the average referral time $\tau_i$ is again exponentially distributed with parameter $p_i\lambda_i$. A proof using generating functions can be found here:
   [Using Moment Generating Functions to solve for exponential distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2121183/using-moment-generating-functions-to-solve-for-exponential-distribution)
2. The minimum of independent exponentially distributed r.vs is again exponentially distributed with parameter $\sum \lambda_i$. For a proof see here: [How to prove that minimum of two exponential random variables is another exponential random variable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/580279/how-to-prove-that-minimum-of-two-exponential-random-variables-is-another-exponen)

Now in our case it should be clear that what we are looking for is $\mathbb{E}(\tau)$, with $\tau= \mathrm{min}\{\tau_1,\tau_2,\tau_3\}$. Hence

$
\mathbb{E}(\tau) = \frac{1}{\sum (p_i\lambda_1)}= 1/(3/4+2/3+8/9) = 83/36
$